# This series is equal to 1 $\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \binom{j-1}{k-1} e^{k \lambda}(1-e^{- \lambda })^{j-k}=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $\lambda>0$ then I want to show

$$\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} \binom{j-1}{k-1} e^{-k \lambda}(1-e^{- \lambda })^{j-k}=1$$

but I don't really see how this could possibly follow.

If anything is unclear, please let me know. Any hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that we have an experiment where the probability of success on any trial is $e^{-\lambda}$. We repeat the experiment independently until we have $k$ successes, and then we stop. Then the "$j$" term in your sum is the probability that the total number of trials is exactly $j$. If we sum over all $j$ (necessarily $\ge k$) we must get $1$.

Comment: I like your interpretation but do you also have a hint how to actually show this?

Comment: From the probabilistic viewpoint, all we need to do is to show that as $j$ goes to infinity, the probability that more than $j$ trials are required has limit $0$. This can be done with quite simple estimates.  But ordinarily one does not make explicit estimates since "with probability $1$ the sequence of experiments must terminate" is obvious.  There is also a manipulational proof    of your identity, using the  Taylor series for $(1-x)^{-k}$.